# How can I remove an app if it doesn't exist in the Play Store anymore?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, es-file-explorer

I have the **ES File Explorer** and the **DU Recorder** apps installed on my phone, but they cannot be found in the Play Store anymore. So, how can I uninstall those apps?

Comment: While the current answer might be sufficient to solve the issue, could you clarify more why you couldn't uninstall them? Like, did you try checking the Android Settings - Apps, then try to uninstall from there? Are they showing a "Disable" button, not "Uninstall"?

Comment: Further, the answer is specific to getting rid of **pre-installed** apps (for apps installed by the user one wouldn't specify `--user-0` as that would just hide the app), so it's not really addressing the question ;)

Comment: I didn't look enough into the problem. I only tried the Play Store and then factory reset the mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play Store is not necessary for installation or uninstallation of apps.

All your installed apps are shown in the app list in Android settings. There you can also uninstall apps.

On most Android versions you can also make a long-touch on an app icon on the launcher and then open the App info page where you can uninstall/disable an app.

Comment: I solved by factory reseting the mobile. This long-touch on the app would probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using adb, I recommend using it on a Linux environment since (for me at least) It's easier to configure.

```
sudo apt install adb
```

Then connect your tablet, be sure that you have your device with USB Debugging enabled.
then, type.

```
adb shell
```

It should connect without a problem, then you have to identify the package you want to delete with.

```
pm packages list <the name of your app or a good hint without the arrows>
```

You should see a result or a list of names that will look something like these

```
com.android.app.calendar
```

Once you are sure about the package name of the app that you wnat to uninstall you have to tun these command.

```
pm uninstall --user-0 <the package name without the arrows>
```

On the other hand, you should be able to uninstall any app you installed just drag and drop... unless is a deprecated google app like google+, and even with this method yo won't be really uninstalling anything, but for your eyes the app is going to disappear.